# Past perfect (earlier past)

Tags: grammar, tense, past-perfect, past-simple

The basic meaning of the past perfect is "*earlier past*". We use past perfect to talk about something that happened before another action in the past, which is usually expressed by the past simple :

> "*The patient had died* before the doctor came."
>
> "The patient died after *the doctor had come*."

But I confronted the following sentence :

> "I started my meal *before Adam arrived*".

I think this sentence should have been like this : **"I had started my meal before Adam arrived."**

Please explain which is ok and why.

Comment: Both are OK. The sentence you found just states in what order the two things happened. _I had started my meal before Adam arrived_ emphasises the fact that the speaker didn't wait for Adam.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, 'started my meal' is an 'earlier action' than 'Adam arrived'. So, past perfect should be used there. It's really confusing!

Comment: I know it is - there is no rule against using the past simple for a series of actions. "I started my meal before Adam arrived because I knew he would have eaten already." "Because I was so hungry I had started my meal before Adam arrived, and he hurried to fetch the soup which I was keeping warm for him."

Comment: The difference is that there are two past actions, out of which one (starting my meal) was earlier than the other (Adam's arriving). So past perfect should be used for 'earlier past' : "had started my meal".

Comment: What is the difference in term of meaning between these 2 examples. Does it mean that I had started  was the reason to make Adam come  to make him hurry

Comment: I have already stated.

Comment: When "after"or "before" are used in a sentence, past perfect is not necessary. "Before" makes the sequence clear, so past simple is fine. You can use past perfect if you choose to.

Comment: Could you please give any reference in support of your view?